# Check if client received http response

Tags: php, http

Is there away to know from php that the http response was received?
I can flush the buffer and then check if it empty but is doesn't mean that the client get the response.

I am looking for the scenario that client generate request and then close the connection.

Comment: HTTP clients often keep the connection open for a while, in case they need to make another call to the same server.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to know if the client received the response, you should require it to make another server call to let the server know. You could do this using AJAX so it doesn't refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted.php might be a solution for your problem.